# If a character with 4 main-hand attacks and the Perfect Multiweapon Fighting epic feat, does using the Haste spell grant them a 5th offhand attack?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats, two-weapon-fighting, epic-tier

A character, **without** using [*haste*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm), has 4 attacks on main hand, and the epic feat [Perfect Multiweapon Fighting](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/epic/feats.htm#perfectMultiweaponFighting):

> You can make as many attacks with each extra weapon as with your primary weapon, using the same base attack bonus. You still take the normal penalties for fighting with two weapons.

Therefore they also can make 4 offhand attacks.

Now if the character were to use *haste* on themselves to get 5 attacks on the main hand, would this mean that they get one additional attack on the second weapon too thanks to the epic feat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes

Nothing about Perfect Multiweapon Fighting (or Perfect Two-Weapon Fighting) puts any limitation or qualification on *how* or *why* you have as many attacks as you do with your primary weapon, it just says that you take get an equal number of attacks with each offhand weapon.

The only requirement is that you are using multiweapon fighting (or two-weapon fighting) to begin with, which means you are making a full attack (Perfect Multiweapon Fighting does not apply to other forms of attacking, such as the standard-action attack, *Tome of Battle* strikes, attacks of opportunity, etc.).